# Allow users to click on elements under a div's blank space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had an element which was the top level dom elemnt. I decided to build a user interface over the top, allowing for items to be placed in `interface-overlay`. It seems I can't click anything inside my `interface-overlay`, but I can click underlying elements?

Sure, I want to click underlying elements, but I also want to be able to click the overlay, and also click the underlying elements where the overlay doesn't have any dom elements covering it.

I used this, but it seems to block for all space:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

If I remove the `pointer-event` attribute, it flips the issue. I can click the overlay but not the underlying elements.

Code pen showing the issue: https://codepen.io/samhabbo/pen/ExymBBK

Comment: Could you copy the code to the question itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to apply `pointer-events: none` to the parent container but then reset it back to `auto` on child elements:

```
.interface-overlay {
  /* ... */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.interface-overlay > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.tile {
  opacity:0.8;
  background-color:#ccc;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.interface-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #FFFF;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.interface-overlay > * {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

button.button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="interface-overlay">
  <button class="button">Overlay button</button>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  Some tile content.
  <button class="button" onclick="alert('test');">Underlying button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The white space will still block the click in this answer, thus, it's not an answer.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be blocking the click to "Underlying button." Are you using an exotic browser, @Dylan?

Comment: The question may be referring to siblings, where your "title" div is also a child of "interface-overlay". In this case the white space is going to occlude the button.

Comment: Well my answer doesn't have that, now does it?

Comment: Fair enough, there's no solution I know-of for the slight change in HTML structure I pointed out, and it's the only reason I found this related question. pointer-events definitely has limitations.